# Неправильный вид страницы JSF на основе шаблона, с использованием PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Проблемы в неправильной отрисовки контекста на странице JSF, созданной на основе шаблона. Т.е. левая часть и строка поиска зафиксированы в шаблоне. А вот контент должен обновляться. Вставляю туда таблицу и "очень странно" отрабатывает.
Код страницы:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jsfcrud.js"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces-aristo" name="theme.css" />
        <base href="#{request.contextPath}/" />
    </h:head>
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="./temp.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" />
                <h:form id="SprVidOborudListForm">
                    <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListSprVidOborudTitle}">
                        <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{sprVidOborudController.items}" var="item"
                                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{sprVidOborudController.selected}"
                                     paginator="true"
                                     rowKey="#{item.id}"
                                     rows="10"
                                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
                                     >
                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="#{bundle.Create}" actionListener="#{sprVidOborudController.prepareCreate}" update=":SprVidOborudCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('SprVidOborudCreateDialog').show()"/>
                                <p:commandButton id="viewButton"   icon="ui-icon-search" value="#{bundle.View}" update=":SprVidOborudViewForm" oncomplete="PF('SprVidOborudViewDialog').show()" disabled="#{empty sprVidOborudController.selected}"/>
                                <p:commandButton id="editButton"   icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="#{bundle.Edit}" update=":SprVidOborudEditForm" oncomplete="PF('SprVidOborudEditDialog').show()" disabled="#{empty sprVidOborudController.selected}"/>
                                <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"  value="#{bundle.Delete}" actionListener="#{sprVidOborudController.destroy}" update=":growl,datalist" disabled="#{empty sprVidOborudController.selected}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <p:column>

                                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListSprVidOborudTitle_nameTip}"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.nameTip}"/>
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
                <ui:include src="jsfpages/sprVidOborud/Create.xhtml"/>
                <ui:include src="jsfpages/sprVidOborud/Edit.xhtml"/>
                <ui:include src="jsfpages/sprVidOborud/View.xhtml"/>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Рисует так:]

Comment: Сказать в чем проблема не видя всего кода (шаблон и кнопки) сложно, но похоже что конфликт стилей. Попробуйте упростить этот шаблон до минимума и просмотрите что получтся а потом добавляйте элемент за  элементом.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Но у меня складывается ощущение, что используя шаблоны, при подстановки данных в раздел     '<ui:define name="content">'    , который переопределяется, каким то образом глушит стили primefaces

Comment: @Mikhail Chibel. Михаил спасибо большое, вы были правы все дело в наложении стилей.